# U-boot: bad magic number

Tags: linux, embedded, openwrt, u-boot

I'am using Arduino Yun and i want mount rootfs over NFS.

I downloaded openwrt sources, build the project and then copied the generated rootfs from `build_dir/target-mips_34kc_musl-1.1.15/root-ar71xx` under `/home/user/srv/nfs/root-ar71xx`

in the uboot prompt the command line i used is :

```
setenv bootargs root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/home/user/srv/nfs/root-ar71xx ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::off; bootm
```

uboot environement variables:

```
ar7240> printenv
bootcmd=bootm 0x9fea0000
bootdelay=4
baudrate=115200
ethaddr=0xb4:0x21:0x8a:0x00:0x00:0x10
ipaddr=192.168.1.2
serverip=192.168.1.1 
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
ethact=eth0
bootargs=root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/home/user/srv/nfs/root-ar71xx     
ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::off

Environment size: 319/65532 bytes
```

But i got :

```
## Booting image at 81000000 ...
Bad Magic Number
```

I read in [this link](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2006-May/014983.html), that there is a kind of encapsulation for the kernel in order to be "known" by U-Boot. Is it the same thing for the rootfs

I have another question but it's not very related to the topic:
After building the project i have several binaries (24) under  `bin/ar71xx/`:

```
openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wzr-hp-ag300h-squashfs-tftp.bin 
openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-mr11u-v1-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wzr-hp-g300nh2-squashfs-factory.bin
...
```

I expect only one kernel image what all these images are supposed to do ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

I change the cmd line to :

```
setenv bootargs root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.1.1:/home/bou6/srv /nfs/root-ar71xx ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::off;  bootm 0x9fea0000
```

and i don"t have `Bad Magic Number` anymore, but still questions:

1- How can we know the load address of the kernel

2- I noticed even though the ethernet cable is not branched the kernel continue to use the default file system flashed on the Yun, is there a method to desactivate this.

Comment: I don't know about Arduino, but usually for U-Boot you have some environment vars that defines where kernel is stored, where to copy and start the kernel. Same thing for the second question: there is a script of boot: analyze.

Comment: For U-Boot issues, you should include in your post the boot log (that shows *all* operations leading up the boot failure) and the environment variables (i.e. from the `printenv` command).  *" there is a kind of encapsulation for the kernel "* -- That would the U-Boot wrapper header installed by the **mkimage** utility.  Apparently the "Bad Magic Number" error you're getting is due to the fact you're booting from RAM that has no kernel image (i.e. the bootm command is using a default address).

Comment: *"How can we know the load address of the kernel"* -- It should  already be in the uImage header, but the uImage should not be loaded at that address.  *"I noticed even though the ethernet cable is not branched ..."* -- I don't understand what you mean by *"not branched"*.  *"the kernel continue to use the default file system"* -- There is no such thing as a *"default (root) filesystem"* (except for the initramfs).  The full boot log would probably explain what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust and @LPs : 1- I will attach the log  when i get back home  2- "is not branched" , i have to say "The board and the NFS server are disconnected ". As @LPs mentioned it seems that it's a uboot configuration(uboot tells the kernel if you don't get the rootfs in the cmd line try the other ) 3- OK for the load address is in the uImage, so in which case the `bootm` is useful

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to just set `bootargs` then call `bootm` ... you need to load a kernel image from somewhere - so the answer to question 1 is "pick any address you like - as long as it is in RAM and there is enough space there to fit the kernel image that you will load into it".

To load the kernel image, set up a tftp server and use the `tftpboot` u-boot command. e.g.

`tftpboot <address> openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wzr-hp-ag300h-squashfs-tftp.bin`

(I am guessing that this is the file containing the kernel image, but probably not) - then you can use the `bootm` command e.g.

`bootm <address>`

You might find some clues [here](http://elinux.org/TFTP_Boot_and_NFS_Root_Filesystems).

As an aside, the `ip=...` kernel command line has this format:

`ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:<dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>`

so I feel like there should be two colons before `off` e.g.

`ip=192.168.1.2:192.168.1.1:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:::off`

but I could be wrong about that.

Re question 2, I would expect the boot to fail and u-boot to fall back to the prompt - not continue on and use the filesystem in flash.

And finally, you need to list all 24 file names from `bin/ar71xx` so we can determine which of them is the kernel image (my guess above doesn't feel right).

Comment: Thank u for the feedback Ok for (1). Concerning the good kernel image, i'am not sure if i'am passing the good kernel image,this is the whole [list](http://paste.ofcode.org/Uv28wiCCqxnQKmfHyPysMH) , thank u for pointing me to the good one. For the command line, i guess using <hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:<dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip> are optional isn't that correct